# Load a controller depending on a value in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I am coding a C# MVC5 View, and would like some help on loading a specific controller create action depending on the value in a drop down list.

Here is my current code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", **some code here** , new { mapLocationId = Model.mapLocationId }, null)
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ItemTypes", new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes), new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The `mapLocationItemTypes` list has the following values:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3

If Item1 is selected, then a controller called Item1 will be loaded, Item2 will load the Item2 controller and Item3 will load the Item3 controller.

How is the best way to code this? Do I need to use javascript? Is there a specific html MVC View attribute that can be used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: on dropdown change you want to post back to other page??

Comment: Preferably by clicking on the "Create New" ActionLink, but if not on that, then on the dropdown click.

Comment: $('#ItemTypes').change(function(){ window.location.href='/' + $(this).val() + '/your action name' });

Comment: @user3736648....worked???

Comment: I have not used JQuery before, do I place this code in the View or somewhere else?

Comment: if you have never use jquery then try this one :--   @Html.DropDownList("ItemTypes", new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes), new { @class = "control-label col-md-2",@onchange="window.location.href='/'+this.value+'// your action name here //'" })